# PHP copying and deleting file and deleting record from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete, file-copying

This code runs when a user hits a delete button on my form. I am trying to copy a file, $picfile, from "/pics/" to "/pics/deletedrecordpics/" and then delete the orginal. Finally, delete the record from the database. Deleting the record from the databse works, but copying the file and deleting the original does nothing. There are no errors in the error log, so I am really confused as to why this code isn't running as I think it should.

```
   $sql = ("select picfile,title,author from $table where id=$delete");             
   $file=mysql_query($sql);
   $resrow = mysql_fetch_row($file); 
   $picfile = $resrow[0]; 
   $title = $resrow[1]; 
   $author = $resrow[2];     
   copy("pics/".$picfile,"pics/deletedrecordpics/".$author." - ".$title." - ".$picfile);    
   unlink("pics/".$picfile);
   $sql = ("DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$delete");
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Show us what the values of `$picfile` `author` and `title` look like

Comment: Relative paths are sometimes not what you think they are. You could try using something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pics/...` to make sure you the paths are correct.

Comment: No luck on that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure unlink should work check if your permissions are set correctly, and if unlink is available on the server installation.

Copy might not be working if "/deletedrecordpics" is a non existing directory, not created yet.

Comment: Well the weird part is a have almost the same code in a delete button on my comtrol panel located in "/adminpanel" and it works perfectly. The code for that is the same except I use $id instead $delete and "../" before all the "pics/" because it's in the adminpanel folder. The permissions are right and the folder exists because the code works with that page.  And I know $delete is gettimg set because the record gets deleted from the database.